# How do you install mate 1.10 from source?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, updates, compiling, mate

I have been trying to install mate 1.10. For several days. The ppa(s) give me 404 errors, and just don't work. the source packages give me an intertwined mess of dependency errors, missing m4 macros, cant install caja, before installing mate-desktop. Cant install mate-desktop, because some other thing isn't exactly right.

Sadly, I haven't found a single install from source instruction any place on the mate-desktop site. Perhaps I am missing it?  I want the updated version of mate, and mate utilities, because they have added features for things I have installed other software which I am not satisfied with. For example, E-book-reader, to read epub files, where in mate 1.10, atril allows you to now read epub files. There are numerous updates I am excited about, in the updated version of mate... but man, I cant figure out how to install this. its all separate packages... no where does it say, install this first.

what is it I'm missing? I understand mate 1.10 isn’t in a repo, thats not what I am  asking. How can I install mate 1.10 from [GIT hub source](https://github.com/mate-desktop) on ubuntu 14.04 mate edition? I have looked at the git hub repos, but I have not found installation instructions.

Comment: What command did you run to install it? It should be `sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment`.

Comment: That will get you the mate 1.8 version version 1.10 doesnt have a reliable ppa, or deb package yet.

Comment: Oh. When is MATE 1.10 meant to be officially released?

Comment: According to the mate-desktop site, it is released.

Comment: I think you may need to install MATE 1.8 and then update the packages from here: http://pub.mate-desktop.org/releases/1.10/.

Comment: After some research, MATE 1.10 isn't in the 15.04 repos. You need to update to 15.10 and MATE will update to 1.10 automatically. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will get you 15.10 and and 1.10.

Comment: Which PPA do you mean and which errors?

Comment: I did figure it out eventually, but I did not post the answer.  Basally you have a distinct order you need to install the various packages in, or it fails.